# crystal report sum different fields in detail section

Tags: crystal-reports, formula, crystal-reports-xi, crystal-reports-server

Is it possible to get a sum from like different field in the detail section?

For example,

```
Location     S1      S2     S3 ...... S40         
room1        5       4      3         1
room2        2       0      4         2
room3        3       1      1         5
```

Is there a way for me to get the sum of for room 1 score from the field S1 to S40? If it can be done in the detail section, that would be great. I don't want to write a formula that is S1 + S2 + S3 ... + S40 but will do if that is the only way of doing it.

Comment: have you tried using cross tab?

Comment: might as well create a stored procedure using Pivot that does everything for you and just print in on the Report. adding s1 to s40 is a bit tedious.